# Taking the log in SAS vs Matlab

Tags: sas

I dont have SAS and cant test this, thus my question. I have a program in SAS that calculates the log values of a bunch of variables (income etc): log(C). I want to transfer this function to Matlab. Should I use log(C) or log10(C) in Matlab to get the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`log()` in SAS

> Returns the natural (base e) logarithm.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/69762/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0urbseuxrkrlyn1tr04y30nt25s.htm